# problems Setting a interval or timeout on my function

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I have a system that checks a database to see if their UserToken is in the database, If it's not it will stop the bot and display an error message, I'm trying to make the bot repeat the same function every minute to see if my database has been updated. Here is the code I'm using:

```js
setInterval(() => {
  const getToken = dtoken => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    MongoClient.connect(url, {
      useUnifiedTopology: true,
    }, function(err, db) {
      if (err) {
        reject(err);
      } else {
        let dbo = db.db("heroku_fkcv4mqk");
        let query = {
          dtoken: dtoken
        };
        dbo.collection("tokens").find(query).toArray(function(err, result) {
          resolve(result);
        });
      }
    })
  })

  bot.on("ready", async message => {

    const result = await getToken(dtoken)
    if (result.length == 1) {
      return
    } else {
      console.error('Error:', 'Your token has been revoked.')
      bot.destroy()
    }
  })

}, 5000);
```

But it doesn't work and I keep getting this error message:

```
(node:9808) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 ready listeners added to [Client]. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
```

if I could get some help with the timeout that would be amazing.

Answer (score 1):

Bot object listens to the event **ready** on each execution in setInterval(). So after every 5 seconds, a new listener is being added on bot object which you have never removed. That's why it is throwing an error that the maximum limit has been reached.

I think you can take the listener out of the setInterval. It will work.

Updated Code:::

```
let isReady = false;
bot.on("ready", () => {
  isReady = true;
});

const getToken = dtoken => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  MongoClient.connect(url, {
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
  }, function(err, db) {
    if (err) {
      reject(err);
    } else {
      let dbo = db.db("heroku_fkcv4mqk");
      let query = {
        dtoken: dtoken
      };
      dbo.collection("tokens").find(query).toArray(function(err, result) {
        resolve(result);
      });
    }
  })
})

setInterval(() => {
  if (isReady) {
    const result = await getToken(dtoken)
    if (result.length == 1) {
      return
    } else {
      console.error('Error:', 'Your token has been revoked.')
      isReady = false
      bot.destroy()
    }
  }      
}, 5000);
```

Comment: if I take the bot listener out of my setinterval the getToken promise wont work inside of the listener

Comment: You are listening on ready event of the bot. From my understanding, it would be fired only once. Is it getting fired at every interval?

Comment: This design does not look promising to me. I think no need to listen to the event at every interval but there must be a state or status property available on Bot object so you can check that before getting token. If not available then put the listener outside of interval and if it is ready then assign a variable and use that inside the interval. I have updated my answer please check.